# How to make NetBeans treat comments the same as everything else when wrapping?

Tags: netbeans

In NetBeans 8.1, with the line wrap setting set to Anywhere, comments in PHP files are somehow treated as magical and special, and ignore this setting.

To reproduce: type a long line of code, such that it wraps. Put `//` at the start of it, and observe that it is now all on one line, and a horizontal scrollbar has appeared.

How can I make it not do this, and wrap comments in the same way as everything else?

Bonus points if anybody can shed any light on why it would do this in the first place — I can't see any logic to it!